# How can I enable the "Personalize my music" setting?

Tags: settings, zune, privacy

I was downloading an app that was unrelated to music, and saw this dialog:

[image: SET UP ACCOUNT]

I did not realize this was part of the new User Agreement from Microsoft, and I unchecked the box so as not to give the app access to my music history.

Now that I know it was unrelated to the app, but more to Zune, I would like to enable this setting.

How can I find it?

Comment: Why not uninstall the app and then install it again to see this window. This time select the checkbox

Comment: @it wasn't message from the app. It was a message from the Marketplace. Before being allowed to continue with the download I had to agree to this new part of the Terms of Use. If you haven't seen this dialog yet, I believe you will be prompted with it if you try to download a new app.

Comment: I have yet to get this notification, so I am guessing here. Is there anything under `Settings(system)->->email+accounts->Windows Live`, or `Settings(applications)->music+videos` (perhaps Zune account settings)?

Comment: @row1 afraid not. The Zune account settings mostly has Xbox Live settings now. I wonder if the message I saw has something to do with Windows 8. I remember the Windows Store asked me to agree to something on the same day.

Comment: This doesn't answer you question...but I don't believe that the option currently does anything. It is likely when this option launches (with xbox music?) there will be a way to turn it on/off.

Comment: Try this.  
Go to the http://www.xbox.com site.  Login there.  You should get a new TOU. Click around through "My Account" and then go into "XBox Music".  Accept any license stuff you get.  Then try pulling down 'tripadvisor' on your phone.  I know it triggers the new TOU. I think you should be OK.  My wife's phone had a similar issue and this seemed to resolve it.

Comment: @JoeHealy I'm afraid I can't verify any answers to this question because I've upgraded phones. If it worked for your wife, I'll be happy to give it the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

This should be in **Settings**, flick to **applications**, choose **music + videos**, then turn on **Connect with Zune**.

Comment: I don't have WP7 anymore, so if this works for anyone, please chime in.